# How to properly read chainlink data feed on Starknet

Tags: chainlink, starknet

On Starknet(testnet), I'd like to read current price of ETH/USD via another contract. However, when calling my contract with starknet cli to see if I can fetch the price, i get following error:

```
Error message: SimpleReadAccessController: address does not have access
```

The function I'm calling looks like this:

```
@view
func chainlink_current_price{syscall_ptr: felt*, range_check_ptr}(token_address: felt) -> (price: felt) {
    alloc_locals;

    with_attr error_message("Failed when getting current price from Chainlink Oracle") {
        let (current_round) = IChainlinkOracle.latest_round_data(token_address);
    }

   return (current_round.answer,);
}
```

The cli command I used is following:

```
 ->  starknet call --address $ADDR --function chainlink_current_price --abi ./build/contract_abi.json --input 0x4cbab9f923b368ec7b0551c107e650ad790170851a4daa4ed780c636c6999de
```

Is there a possibility of obtaining the access?

Comment: There are 2 smart contracts for Data feed, one is an aggregator contract and the other one is a proxy contract on the aggregator. You want to use the proxy instead of the aggregator. Can you check if you are using the correct one?

Comment: Well, I got the address from [Chainlink docs](https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/price-feeds/addresses?network=starknet). But when looking at [Starkscan](https://testnet.starkscan.co/contract/0x04cbab9f923b368ec7b0551c107e650ad790170851a4daa4ed780c636c6999de#read-contract), it seems like the contract has [IAggregator](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-starknet/blob/develop/contracts/src/chainlink/cairo/ocr2/IAggregator.cairo) interface. Do you know where I can find the address for proxy consumer?

Comment: The addresses listed [here](https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/price-feeds/addresses?network=starknet) are the proxy address.